# Have column auto assigned through query

Tags: mysql, sql

Essentially I want a column to give itself a value based off a value from another table when it gets inserted.

```
version_numbers (table) (id, ...): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
application_debug (table) (debug_id, ver_id ...)
```

On insertion, debug_id is set by the auto increment, but I would also like ver_id to be set with a query like this `ver_id = SELECT MAX(id) FROM Version_Numbers`

In this example, when inserting into `application_debug` I would like `ver_id` to be populated with the greatest id stored in `version_numbers`. I'm aware this can be done in multiple statements, but was wondering if there was a way to make the default values of a column be evaluated through a query on insertion.

Comment: https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use select from as below:

`insert into application_debug(ver_id) select max(id) from version_numbers;`

If you want to insert any static values into application_debug which are not from verions_numbers, then you can write the query as below:

`insert into application_debug(ver_id,col2) select max(id),'val2' from version_numbers;`

Comment: Although this would likely work fine, I believe the answer suggested by Phil, someone who commented on the main post, MySQL triggers are likely a more universal answer to the question. Thanks.